# Simple Search Program PHP/SQL

Tags: php, html, sql

Fixed: Thanks everyone for your help, for those who needs to start somewhere you could use this as your reference

I'm trying to study PHP SQL HTML, and I'm having a hard time on running my code properly, Can you please help me out. I've looked at a lot of examples already, but I cant get this to work, my html form doesn't show up. This is a program that will search what the user inputs in the search form and it would look it up on the sql database.

```
     <html>
  <head>
    <meta  http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;  charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Search  Contacts</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Search  Contacts Details</h3>
    <p>You  may search either by first or last name</p>
    <form  method="post" action="#"  id="searchform">
      <input  type="text" name="name">
      <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
    </form>

<?php
$servername = "xxx";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "Staff";
$myquery = $_POST["name"];

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
```

}
    // SQL query

```
if (!empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $sql = "select ID, FirstName, LastName, Email, PhoneNumber from Userlist where FirstName LIKE '%". $myquery  ."%'" ;

    //Get query on the database
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    //Check results
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
          echo "id:" . $row["ID"] . 
               " - Name: " . $row["LastName"]. " " . $row["FirstName"]. // Correct here 
               " - Email: " . $row["Email"] . 
               " - PhoneNumber: " . $row["PhoneNumber"]. "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
}

    mysqli_close($conn);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting exactly? check your errors log

Comment: You forgot the ' in the SQL statement.

Comment: Sorry but I dont see any errors, Im writing this on notepad and running this via web browser to see if it works, and it doesn't show anything. If i remove the php codes i could see the forms, I tested my connection to the database and i was able to connect, but when i place the php codes for searching, i dont see my html search form anymore.

Comment: What server are you using? We need to see error messages because if your HTML is not showing it means that there's a PHP error that's not letting anything else load.

Comment: Hi Im using vmware with ubuntu, and installed LAMPP, and I just create a .php file on the root drive and test if it works in the browser, I dont know where i could see logfiles.. sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing the closing curly brace after the if (!$conn) { }

Comment: Yes I have LAMP on my ubuntu system, and I am able to output tables from phpmyadmin without the html block of codes, but if i combine them, nothing shows.

Comment: Your comment wasn't there when i originally loaded the page... The php won't stop that page loading, You have a <p> tag bafore the body tag though, Try taking that out.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry earlier. I have taken out the <p> tag before the body tag but still nothing shows.

Comment: what's the query after the form action url, the `?go` part ? As you're only submitting to self would action="#" not do ?

Comment: this is what you mean i should do? action="#", I've tried running it now but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Right, Comment out all the PHP, Now does the form show  ?

Comment: if yes then uncomment the PHP and wrap it all in an if else, I'll update my answer in a mo with a code snip

Comment: Yes, the form shows and if i edit my php script up to // Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

echo "<p>$myquery</p>"

?> i am able to output what i type in my search

Comment: You're missing the closing curly brace after if (!$conn) {

Comment: It's running now thank you, coculd you suggest a program which i could use for me to see any logs?

Comment: don't know much about lamp but i would say they have logs. set error_reporting(E_ALL);  when your on your own server, NEVER in public domains though. Don't forget to mark the question answered

Answer (score 3):

You need to correct the SQL statement with `'` to `LIKE`.

```
$sql = "select ID, FirstName, LastName, Email, PhoneNumber  
       from Userlist where FirstName LIKE '%". $myquery  ."%'" ;
```

Also, as you `$myquery` variable deped on `$_POST`, so I think you should do something like following:

```
if (!empty($_POST["name"])) {

    $myquery = $_POST["name"];

    $sql = "select ID, FirstName, LastName, Email, PhoneNumber 
           from Userlist where FirstName LIKE '%". $myquery  ."%'" ;

    //Get query on the database
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    //Check results
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
          echo "id:" . $row["ID"] . 
               " - Name: " . $row["LastName"]. " " . $row["FirstName"]. // Correct here 
               " - Email: " . $row["Email"] . 
               " - PhoneNumber: " . $row["PhoneNumber"]. "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
}
```

and make sure, ***you form action is same as the current page your PHP code belong to.***

Comment: That is not the correct fix though:

$sql = "select ID, FirstName, LastName, Email, PhoneNumber  
       from Userlist where FirstName LIKE '%" . $myquery . "%'"

Comment: @devJunk you wrote the *same* thing as thecodeparadox. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: He edited it. The second ' was before the % ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help, but my html form still doesn't show up...

Comment: @thecodeparadox thanks for this, by placing the !empty is a good handler when there's no output. I've also edited my script now but i still can't get my html form to show

Answer (score 0):

Try with an echo for each line of output. 
Secondly pay attention to the ' suggestion.
Thirdly escape your post variable for security.

Comment: Thanks, I have followed the ' suggestion, I've used the $_POST for getting the value from the form method on my html code, that's what i saw somewhere. My main problem now is that my html search form doesn't show

Comment: Are you talking about the the form that the user inputs into or are you trying to output the form with php?